# Can I force the zoom to be square shaped?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I have a subplot in a dash app and right now someone can drag their mouse and highlight in any shape. Can I force that zoom window to be square shaped? To be clear, they can't zoom in any shape but they can zoom in any rectangular shape.

This is an example of what I want the zoom to be - https://plotly.com/python/axes/#fixed-ratio-axes

I tried to do that, but it didn't work because I have a subplot with a shared x axis.

This is my existing dashboard

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

Comment: In Plotly, zooming is always in a rectangle shape.

Comment: What other shapes does the user have?

Comment: I want it to only be squares rather than rectangles. See how in the example chart you can only zoom in squares but not rectangles

Comment: I guess that's not quite the right way to put it. What I mean is that if you put your mouse on the chart and click and move up and down, the zoom also goes left and right. That's not the default behavior

Comment: In the example you referred, the shape of zooming is rectangle, not square.

Comment: This one is the squared zooming https://plotly.com/python/axes/#decreasing-the-domain-spanned-by-an-axis

Comment: Yeah the one under "fixed ratio with a compressed axis"

Comment: I do not think, plotly supports this option in the meanwhile. You can see https://community.plotly.com/t/enable-only-square-selection-zoom-on-the-graph/489/2

Comment: I don't mean literal squares, I'm just trying to replicate the chart under fixed ratio with a compressed axis

Comment: It works, by setting `fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1)` the ratio between the two axes is properly fixed, and the rectangular shape of the zoom window as well. Now if that shape is a rectangle, this is because your plots are rectangles, you won't obtain squares with a 800x600 layout splitted in 2 rows (8:3), you need a 1:1 ratio (not exactly as margins, subplots vertical_spacing etc. will affect the final ratio, but you get the idea).